# InnerJoin in CakePHP 3 returns no rows

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to learn CakePHP 3, but I have run into a problem:

I have two tables *languages* and *rich_text_elements*, and want to join them in the following manner:

```
$all = $this->find()->
select(['i18n','Language.long_name'])->
innerJoin(['Language' => 'languages'], ['Language.i18n' => 'RichTextElements.i18n'])->
group('RichTextElements.i18n')->
order(['RichTextElements.i18n'])->all();
```

The following query is produced:

```
SELECT RichTextElements.i18n AS `RichTextElements__i18n`, 
Language.long_name AS `Language__long_name` 
FROM rich_text_elements RichTextElements 
INNER JOIN languages Language ON Language.i18n = :c0 
GROUP BY RichTextElements.i18n  ORDER BY RichTextElements.i18n;
```

If I replace ":c0" with "RichTextElements.i18n", this query runs fine alone (in HeidiSql) and returns five rows of data, exactly as I expect it to.

But CakePHP returns an empty set!

The problem seem related to the `innerJoin()` because if I modify the query to select only from the *RichTextElements* table, it will return five rows as expected, in CakePHP:

Runs fine:

```
$all = $this->find()->
select(['i18n'])->
group('RichTextElements.i18n')->
order(['RichTextElements.i18n'])->all();
```

Anyone see what I don't see?

Comment: Just a guess, so I don't put this as an answer. I think cake consider RichTextElements.i18n as a string and quotes it. Try `['Language.i18n = RichTextElements.i18n']` in your ON condition

Comment: That was probably the cause arilia! The solution Inigo presented below works, and I believe you just explained _why_ it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the API:

> Conditions can be expressed [...] using a string for comparing columns, or string with already quoted literal values. Additionally it is possible to use conditions expressed in arrays or expression objects.

Taken from [Query::join() | Using conditions and types](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_join).

Try the following:

```
$all = $this->find()
    ->select(['i18n','Language.long_name'])
    ->innerJoin(
        ['Language' => 'languages'],
        ['Language.i18n' => new \Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('RichTextElements.i18n')])
    ->group('RichTextElements.i18n')
    ->order(['RichTextElements.i18n'])->all();
```

This should also work:

```
$all = $this->find()
    ->select(['i18n','Language.long_name'])
    ->innerJoin(
        ['Language' => 'languages'],
        ['Language.i18n = RichTextElements.i18n'])
    ->group('RichTextElements.i18n')
    ->order(['RichTextElements.i18n'])->all();
```

Comment: Interesting, it worked! I followed your third advice, and put the ON requirement as one string 'Language.i18n = RichTextElements.i18n' instead of 'Language.i18n' => 'RichTextElements.i18n'.

Comment: I have quoteIdentifiers set to false in the config/app.php file. It is a pretty vanilla installation of cake3, with no changes from the defaults. What made you believe I had turned it on?

Comment: Although the solution worked, I think I got mixed up with another S.O. question I was dealing with :) Nevertheless, I will edit it to provide a more accurate explanation.